# Force portrait orientation IOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, superclass

I'm trying to force portrait orientation on iphone. So i try this :

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Landscape
}
```

But i have an error :
**"Method does not override any method from its superclass"**

Answer (score 0):

*supportedInterfaceOrientations()* is a function from *UIViewController*. If you are getting this error "Method does not override any method from its superclass" which means your class is not inherited from UIViewController. Maybe you can give additional info about the class you try to implement an orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like the below code snippet,

```swift
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    return .landscape
}
```

This has been converted into a property now and you should override them and return a value like a computed property.
Since your question says you are trying to force a **portrait** orientation, you should return `.portrait` or `UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait` instead